# "I2C transfer failed" flooding the logs

Tags: i2c, archlinux

I recently got a RPI 3, on which I installed ArchLinux, aarch64 version. I just saw that an I2C error message is flooding the logs. Exact error is:

```
kernel: i2c-bcm2835 3f805000.i2c: i2c transfer failed: 100
```

This is logged 5 times every 10 seconds.

What's strange is that RPI 3 Soc is a Broadcom 2837, not 2835. Also I don't have anything plugged in the GPIOs, so I don't know why this happens. Could it be something that's on the board itself? How do I find out, and how can I get rid of it?

Comment: https://archlinuxarm.org/platforms/armv8/broadcom/raspberry-pi-3 -> *"Some of the hardware on the board may not work, or it may perform poorly."*  You should use a Pi specific distro, not a generic one, particularly if you are unfamiliar with the board.  Arch has an ARMv7 distro for the Pi 2/3 which should work.

Comment: I know that, but I want to run mongodb on it, of which the 32-bit version is not supported and very impractical.

Comment: Someone may come along with a solution but don't hold your breath.   You might have better luck compiling the Pi branch kernel as 64-bit and using that -- I *think* this has been done but there are, again, some components which don't work.  However, if you don't have much experience compiling the linux kernel, this is probably a rabbit hole.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE**: Actually... this doesn't fully resolve the issue. These messages are now in the log:

```
i2c-bcm2835 3f805000.i2c: i2c transfer timed out
```

Deeper debugging is necessary to figure out what is hooked up to this particular I2C controller on the board.

---

Here is what worked for me to resolve this issue. First, I noticed this earlier in the kernel log:

```
i2c-bcm2835 3f805000.i2c: Could not read clock-frequency property
```

To fix it, edit the Device Tree Blob to add 'clock-frequency' property to that particular I2C module (the property is already set for the other I2C modules, so not sure why it wasn't for this one). Here is a patch and commands to decompile, patch, and recompile the DTB:

```
--- /boot/dtbs/broadcom/bcm2837-rpi-3-b.dts     2017-06-10 00:48:48.000000000 -0400
+++ /boot/dtbs/broadcom/bcm2837-rpi-3-b-i2c.dts 2017-06-10 00:30:36.000000000 -0400
@@ -465,20 +465,21 @@
                i2c@7e805000 {
                        compatible = "brcm,bcm2835-i2c";
                        reg = <0x7e805000 0x1000>;
                        interrupts = <0x2 0x15>;
                        clocks = <0x4 0x14>;
                        #address-cells = <0x1>;
                        #size-cells = <0x0>;
                        status = "okay";
                        linux,phandle = <0xd>;
                        phandle = <0xd>;
+                       clock-frequency = <0x186a0>;
                };

                vec@7e806000 {
                        compatible = "brcm,bcm2835-vec";
                        reg = <0x7e806000 0x1000>;
                        clocks = <0x4 0x18>;
                        interrupts = <0x2 0x1b>;
                        status = "okay";
                        power-domains = <0xc 0x7>;
                };
```

Save the above as `/boot/dtbs/broadcom/bcm2837-rpi-3-b-i2c.patch` and:

```
pacman -S dtc
cd /boot/dtbs/broadcom
cp bcm2837-rpi-3-b{,.stock}.dtb
dtc -I dtb -O dts > bcm2837-rpi-3-b.dts
patch -p0 bcm2837-rpi-3-b.dts < bcm2837-rpi-3-b-i2c.patch
dtc -I dts -O dtb > bcm2837-rpi-3-b.dtb
sync
```

Reboot, and there should be no more error nor the log message flood.

PS. This kind of troubleshooting question might be better for the Arch  Linux ARM forum.

Answer (score 1):

To add a comment to alexei's answer:

In the peripheral documentation of [BCM2835](https://datasheets.raspberrypi.com/bcm2835/bcm2835-peripherals.pdf) (looks like it is still valid for RPi 3B+), the device at bus address 0x7e805000 is an i2c controller, Broadcom calls it BSC2. There is also an interesting note:

> Note that the BSC2 master is used dedicated with the HDMI interface and should not be accessed by user programs.

Also the [commit message here](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/3ce82be9ae3d6d6da9984050147da4736b5090d9) refers to it as i2c2 and it seems special.

From [these sources](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/display/brcm%2Cbcm-vc4.txt), i2c2 device is used as ddc for hdmi device.

I can't find any reason why clock-frequency for i2c2 is left without a value.